# Multi-cell array formula for array of unknown length

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have a range containing data on one sheet and want to slice out and manipulate various columns using array formulae in another sheet.

So as an example, I might want to reproduce one column using the formula:

```
=INDEX(originalData,0,MATCH("product_name",OFFSET(originalData,0,0,1),0))
```

where `originalData` is a dynamic named range which applies to all the data contained on the first sheet. So it looks across the headings and returns the column whose heading is "product_name".

The issue I have is that the data has a varying number of rows - anything from 50,000 to several hundred thousand. Is it possible to define an array formula so it returns an array of a dynamic size rather than having to preselect a ton of rows which I may not need and slow the whole thing down a ton?

(I know that this works in Google Sheets - is there an equivalent?)

EDIT - Example for clarity:

In sheet 1:

[image]
`originalData` is defined as `=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),COUNTA($1:$1))`, but this is just really to save having to type this all out several times in the formulas in sheet 2.

In sheet 2:

I want to use this data to create a new data set, e.g. the below, which takes data from the original data source, sometimes direct, sometimes manipulated (e.g. price might be looked up from elsewhere).

[image]

However, let's take the example of column A which should be the same as column A on sheet 1. In Google sheets I would use a formula something like `=INDEX(originalData,0,MATCH("product_id",OFFSET(originalData,-1,0,1),0))` in cell A1, and this would return an array equal to the number of rows as the array referred to.

However, as far as I am aware, in Excel you have to preselect the range in which you want the returned array to go, and therefore you need to know the size of the array in advance in order to select the correct number of rows. Since the size of `originalData` will vary whenever updated, I want to avoid this and have the size of the returned array vary to match.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You state that originalData "is a dynamic named range", yet then follow that by saying that it "covers all rows and columns on the first sheet". Can you clarify in what way this Named Range is "dynamic"?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - I meant all populated rows and columns in the first sheet, i.e. the data source. I'll amend.

Comment: So how have you set this Named Range so that it covers "populated" rows only?

Comment: it uses an offset, so something like offset(A1,0,0,counta(A:A),counta(1:1)) - however, I don't see how this is particularly relevant? I could use any method to define the range I am referring to, my concern is how an array formula can return an array of unknown length?

Comment: But isn't the "data" referred to in "The issue I have is that the data has a varying number of rows - anything from 50,000 to several hundred thousand." the very same as originalData?

Comment: Perhaps you should add a small table representing a vastly-reduced version of your real data together with some expected results.

Comment: I've added an example - hope this is clearer. It's really a very simple question, I'm sorry I haven't been able to explain it properly!

Comment: Without VBA, you cannot preset the size of the range to which a given formula applies. You can, however, choose a suitably low, though sufficient, upper bound on the number of expected returns at any given time, then place a formula in cells up to that upper bound which contain a simple clause to return e.g. a blank in cells beyond the actual number of returns.

Comment: XOR LX's answer is 100% accurate.